# Assigning HTML value to PHP variable - best practice?

Tags: php, html

Right now I'm assigning HTML to a variable the usual way:

```
$var = <<<END
<blah>...</blah>
END;
```

The big disadvantage is that my IDE won't treat this as HTML, and so it won't highlight the code. Is there a way to do it that will keep the HTML outside of the `<?php ?>` tags so that code highlighting will work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're printing, you could always just exit PHP and go back in whenever you like:

```
<?php

function print_header() {
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>

    <?php
}

function print_footer() {
    ?>

        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
}

print_header();
print_footer();
```

Alternatively, you could use buffers to use that technique to assign them to variables:

```
<?php

function print_header() {
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>

    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

function print_footer() {
    ob_start();
    ?>

        </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}

echo print_header();
echo print_footer();
```

Comment: +1 PHP is a templating langugage. Use it, don't fight it! When you say `$var= 'a load of HTML';` or `echo '<a>some html with insecure $interpolations</a>';` you are doing it wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid this as much as possible by using a template engine such as Smarty -> http://www.smarty.net/

Comment: Yes, a template engine is definitely how you want to handle HTML contents in general.

Comment: PHP is already a templating engine in itself. Smarty is overrated.